# Want perl regexp substitution to start over and avoid `1 while` trick

Tags: regex, perl

Example: I want to remove duplicate chars in `$s` like this:

```
my $s = 'aabbbcbbac';
1 while $s =~ s/((.).*)\2/$1/;
print $s, "\n";                     #prints abc
```

Is there a simple and short way to avoid the `1 while` trick and remove duplicates with just one `s///g`? Getting it to "start over" somehow? by using `\G` or some sort of look-behind|-ahead? Just adding `/g` is not the solution here.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `while` loop?

Comment: Just wondered many times about this, for such a common pattern there "ought to be" a more straightforward solution with s/// alone. There is nothing wrong with `1 while s///` as far as I know. (As a beginner, before I realized that s/// has a return value, I remember spending time trying with `/g` or `while(1){my$old=$_;s/some/thing/g;last if $_ eq $old}`)

Comment: The `while` solution is more than one pattern match. That's the whole point of it. You are running multiple distinct substitutions. Not everything can be shoved into a single pattern, and most things shouldn't.

Comment: Re "*for such a common pattern there*", It's not. You're doing something wrong if you're calling s/// repeatedly.

Answer (score 8):

This could be done with a variable-length look-behind, which isn't allowed. But a variable-length look-behind is equivalent to a variable-length look-ahead on the reverse of the input, so we have this trick available:

`reverse` the string, delete chars using a look-ahead, and `reverse` again

```
$t = reverse $s;
$t =~ s/(.)(?=.*\1)//sg;
$s = reverse $t;
```

If you have Perl 5.14 or better and can use the `/r` modifier on substitutions, you get

```
$s = reverse( reverse($s) =~ s/(.)(?=.*\1)//grs );
```

Answer (score 6):

A non-regular expression solution could be built using `split`, `grep` and `join` with a lookup hash. It's probably not much more readable though.

```
my $s = 'aabbbcbbac';
my %seen;
$s = join '', grep { !$seen{$_}++ } split //, $s;
print $s, "\n";
```

This outputs

```
abc
```

Comment: Ok, a good answer for removing duplicates (except you don't need `&&$_`), but my question wasn't really about removing duplicates, that was just a suitable example to illustrate.

Comment: @KjetilS. then you should be more clear with your question.

Comment: @Kjetil S., Re "*just a suitable example to illustrate.*", As you can see, it wasn't a suitable example. I can't think of a single one. Can you? If not, the implication of simbabque stands: There are better ways.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to get a s/// to match more than twice at any one position in the original string, because a non-zero width match will advance to the next position and two zero-width matches at the same position are not allowed to avoid endless loops.